# I hope you live / I hope you will live

Tags: differences, tenses, present-tense, future

What is a correct way to say it: *I hope you live for many years.* or *I hope you will live for many years*?
I am really confused by it since I've seen quotes of famous writers that said *live* but an English teacher I know says it is not the correct way.

Edit: a quote by F. Scott Fitzgerald:

> I hope you live a life you're proud of. If you find you're not, I hope
>   you have the strength to start all over again.

Comment: Please show those sentences where you have seen it.

Comment: I'd like to second @kuldeep — please show us one of these quotes from a famous writer! Out of context, either of these phrases sounds a little odd/Jedi.

Comment: I'd not ellipt so far: _I hope you live a life you're proud of. And I hope that if you find you're not doing, you will have the strength to start all over again._

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Given the right context, the following versions all work:

> A: "I had a bit of health scare recently. Thankfully it turned out I didn't have lung cancer after all".
>
> B: "That's great news -- I hope you live for many years".
>
> "That's great news -- I hope you will live for many years".
>
> "That's great news -- I hope you live many years".
>
> "That's great news -- I hope you will live many years".

As the examples given above show, when a statement expresses a wish that something will happen in the future, the inclusion of *will* is optional because it is implied in the wish. *For* is also optional, for the same reason.

But note that the subject/verb number agreement may need to be adjusted. Compare:

> 1) "I hope you live [for] many years". [No adjustment necessary -- the verb form for the present indicative of *live* is the same as the infinitive for both singular *you* and plural *you*.]
>
> 2a) "I hope he **lives** [for] many years".
>
> 2b) "I hope he **will live** [for] many years". [Adjustment needed -- the present indicative verb form for the second person singular adds *-s* to the infinitive (**lives** versus **live**).]

Comment: Long live the king!

Comment: But I'm anti-royalist!  :-)

Comment: Great answer, thank you very much for the explanation!

Comment: You're very welcome! :-)